# html video tag content not getting fit with the container

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am working with web application where i have a portion like below

```
    <div class="container">
      <video id="video" autoplay>
       <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
```

The video has original size 640*360. I want to fit this video to a container having size 350*180.

I have adjusted the height by giving a height 180 to the video elemnt. But the width also proportionally changed which is less than my container size.

Here is what i have tried out so far http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/911/

I need to adjust the width of the video such that it fits inside the container.

Any helps appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in css, for me it is working:

```css
video{
  position: fixed;
  width:350px !important;
  height: atuo !important;
  margin: 0;

}
.container{
  position:fixed;
    margin:0;
  width:350px;
  height:180px;
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: @ Marek Cieślar Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way: http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/921/

```
video{
  width: 100%;
}

.container{
  width:350px;
  height:180px;
  background:red;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time:) But this doesn't work with windows edge browser or IE.

Comment: Looks better but the height of the video got increased to 196px,which goes outside the container.

Comment: I think we should do some scaling to get this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiladitya/qum5feer/1/).

html

```
<div class="container">
<video id="video" autoplay width="350" height="180">
    <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

css

```
video{
  height:180px;    
}

.container{
  width:350px;
  height:180px;
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: did yo noticed that there is space on both sides of the video tag. It doesn't exactly fit.